# Two factor authentication with spring security oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2, two-factor-authentication

I'm looking for ideas how to implement two factor authentication (2FA) with spring security OAuth2. The requirement is that the user needs two factor authentication only for specific applications with sensitive information. Those webapps have their own client ids.

One idea that popped in my mind would be to "mis-use" the scope approval page to force the user to enter the 2FA code/PIN (or whatever).

Sample flows would look like this:

**Accessing apps without and with 2FA**

- User is logged out
- User accesses app A which does not require 2FA
- Redirect to OAuth app, user logs in with username and password
- Redirected back to app A and user is logged in
- User accesses app B which also does not require 2FA
- Redirect to OAuth app, redirect back to app B and user is directly logged in
- User accesses app S which *does* require 2FA
- Redirect to OAuth app, user needs to additionally provide the 2FA token
- Redirected back to app S and user is logged in

**Directly accessing app with 2FA**

- User is logged out
- User accesses app S which *does* require 2FA
- Redirect to OAuth app, user logs in with username and password, user needs to additionally provide the 2FA token
- Redirected back to app S and user is logged in

Do you have other ideas how to apporach this?

Comment: A great implementation, IMO: [Multi-factor Authentication with Spring Boot and OAuth2](https://sultanov.dev/blog/multi-factor-authentication-with-spring-boot-and-oauth2/)

Comment: @Cepr0 I've tried to implement this, but the second-factor step fails with this error thrown in `org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider`:



`throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
     "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials",
     "Bad credentials"));`

Any clues?

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne maybe my example will be helpful: https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-oauth2-mfa-demo . But I need to warn you that password grant is deprecated: https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/issues/94

Comment: @Cepr0 Thank you for sharing! I am learning a lot using both these repositories. But I am faced with the same issue looking at your code, I don't understand how you can pass "N/A" or "" to AuthenticationManager. In my case, `DaoAuthenticationProvider` cannot accept an empty password.

Comment: My architecture resembles the link that you shared on June 7th more than yours; so I have 2 token granters (otp and password). But when I call the `authenticationManager.authenticate(...)` as part of the second factor (i.e. in `MfaTokenGranter`), that's where I see the bad credentials exception.

Comment: @AlexandreCassagne [here](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-oauth2-mfa-demo/blob/bcb9d0835838ade81c22f8fd4e802551e0e55a4f/auth-service/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/authservice/config/SecurityConfig.java#L34) is implemented `UserDetailsService` (with lambda) which returns custom UserDetails (which is used by AuthenticationManager). And [here](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-oauth2-mfa-demo/blob/bcb9d0835838ade81c22f8fd4e802551e0e55a4f/auth-service/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/authservice/dto/CustomUserDetails.java#L12) is implemented custom UserDetails with 'n/a' password.

Comment: @Cepr0 Thank you so much!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So this is how two factor authentication has been implemented finally:

A filter is registered for the /oauth/authorize path after the spring security filter:

```
@Order(200)
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected void afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic twoFactorAuthenticationFilter = servletContext.addFilter("twoFactorAuthenticationFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy(AppConfig.TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_BEAN));
        twoFactorAuthenticationFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/oauth/authorize");
        super.afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
    }
}
```

This filter checks if the user hasn't already authenticated with a 2nd factor (by checking if the `ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED` authority isn't available) and creates an OAuth `AuthorizationRequest` which is put into the session. The user is then redirected to the page where he has to enter the 2FA code:

```
/**
 * Stores the oauth authorizationRequest in the session so that it can
 * later be picked by the {@link com.example.CustomOAuth2RequestFactory}
 * to continue with the authoriztion flow.
 */
public class TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    private OAuth2RequestFactory oAuth2RequestFactory;

    @Autowired
    public void setClientDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        oAuth2RequestFactory = new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
    }

    private boolean twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return authorities.stream().anyMatch(
            authority -> ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED.equals(authority.getAuthority())
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Check if the user hasn't done the two factor authentication.
        if (AuthenticationUtil.isAuthenticated() && !AuthenticationUtil.hasAuthority(ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED)) {
            AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = oAuth2RequestFactory.createAuthorizationRequest(paramsFromRequest(request));
            /* Check if the client's authorities (authorizationRequest.getAuthorities()) or the user's ones
               require two factor authenticatoin. */
            if (twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(authorizationRequest.getAuthorities()) ||
                    twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities())) {
                // Save the authorizationRequest in the session. This allows the CustomOAuth2RequestFactory
                // to return this saved request to the AuthenticationEndpoint after the user successfully
                // did the two factor authentication.
                request.getSession().setAttribute(CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, authorizationRequest);

                // redirect the the page where the user needs to enter the two factor authentiation code
                redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response,
                        ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                            .path(TwoFactorAuthenticationController.PATH)
                            .toUriString());
                return;
            } else {
                request.getSession().removeAttribute(CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private Map<String, String> paramsFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
            params.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0]);
        }
        return params;
    }
}
```

The `TwoFactorAuthenticationController` that handles entering the 2FA-code adds the authority `ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED` if the code was correct and redirects the user back to the /oauth/authorize endpoint.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(TwoFactorAuthenticationController.PATH)
public class TwoFactorAuthenticationController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwoFactorAuthenticationController.class);

    public static final String PATH = "/secure/two_factor_authentication";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String auth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, ....) {
        if (AuthenticationUtil.isAuthenticatedWithAuthority(ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED)) {
            LOG.info("User {} already has {} authority - no need to enter code again", ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED);
            throw ....;
        }
        else if (session.getAttribute(CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) == null) {
            LOG.warn("Error while entering 2FA code - attribute {} not found in session.", CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            throw ....;
        }

        return ....; // Show the form to enter the 2FA secret
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String auth(....) {
        if (userEnteredCorrect2FASecret()) {
            AuthenticationUtil.addAuthority(ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED);
            return "forward:/oauth/authorize"; // Continue with the OAuth flow
        }

        return ....; // Show the form to enter the 2FA secret again
    }
}
```

A custom `OAuth2RequestFactory` retrieves the previously saved `AuthorizationRequest` from the session if available and returns that or creates a new one if none can be found in the session.

```
/**
 * If the session contains an {@link AuthorizationRequest}, this one is used and returned.
 * The {@link com.example.TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter} saved the original AuthorizationRequest. This allows
 * to redirect the user away from the /oauth/authorize endpoint during oauth authorization
 * and show him e.g. a the page where he has to enter a code for two factor authentication.
 * Redirecting him back to /oauth/authorize will use the original authorizationRequest from the session
 * and continue with the oauth authorization.
 */
public class CustomOAuth2RequestFactory extends DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory {

    public static final String SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "savedAuthorizationRequest";

    public CustomOAuth2RequestFactory(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        super(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public AuthorizationRequest createAuthorizationRequest(Map<String, String> authorizationParameters) {
        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = (AuthorizationRequest) session.getAttribute(SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            if (authorizationRequest != null) {
                session.removeAttribute(SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
                return authorizationRequest;
            }
        }

        return super.createAuthorizationRequest(authorizationParameters);
    }
}
```

This custom OAuth2RequestFactory is set to the authorization server like:

```xml
<bean id="customOAuth2RequestFactory" class="com.example.CustomOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="clientDetailsService" />
</bean>

<!-- Configures the authorization-server and provides the /oauth/authorize endpoint -->
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="approvalStoreUserApprovalHandler" redirect-resolver-ref="redirectResolver"
    authorization-request-manager-ref="customOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <oauth:authorization-code authorization-code-services-ref="authorizationCodeServices"/>
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>
```

When using java config you can create a `TwoFactorAuthenticationInterceptor` instead of the `TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter` and register it with an `AuthorizationServerConfigurer` with

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig implements AuthorizationServerConfigurer {
    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .addInterceptor(twoFactorAuthenticationInterceptor())
            ...
            .requestFactory(customOAuth2RequestFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptor twoFactorAuthenticationInterceptor() {
        return new TwoFactorAuthenticationInterceptor();
    }
}
```

The `TwoFactorAuthenticationInterceptor` contains the same logic as the `TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter` in its `preHandle` method.

Comment: I changed the impl to use java 8 sterams, so the Query and Predicate classes are not needed anymore. You can find the AuthenticationUtil [here](https://gist.github.com/ractive/f9b792edcf589ef43b8c644635c4ac86).

Comment: I placed a large bounty on a far-downstream implementation of a similar algorithm in Spring Boot.  Seems to only fail at close to the last step.  Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061697/invalid-xsrf-token-at-oauth-token

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an example app, no.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't make the accepted solution work. I have been working on this for a while, and finally I wrote my solution by using the ideas explained here and on this thread "[null client in OAuth2 Multi-Factor Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899386/null-client-in-oauth2-multi-factor-authentication)"

Here is the GitHub location for the working solution for me: 
https://github.com/turgos/oauth2-2FA

I appreciate if you share your feedback in case you see any issues or better approach.

Below you can find the key configuration files for this solution.

**AuthorizationServerConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {

        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("ClientId")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .scopes("user_info")
                .authorities(TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED)
                .autoApprove(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .requestFactory(customOAuth2RequestFactory());
    }


    @Bean
    public DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory customOAuth2RequestFactory(){
        return new CustomOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean twoFactorAuthenticationFilterRegistration(){
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(twoFactorAuthenticationFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/oauth/authorize");
        registration.setName("twoFactorAuthenticationFilter");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter twoFactorAuthenticationFilter(){
        return new TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter();
    }
}
```

**CustomOAuth2RequestFactory**

```
public class CustomOAuth2RequestFactory extends DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.class);

    public static final String SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "savedAuthorizationRequest";


    public CustomOAuth2RequestFactory(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        super(clientDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public AuthorizationRequest createAuthorizationRequest(Map<String, String> authorizationParameters) {

        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = (AuthorizationRequest) session.getAttribute(SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            if (authorizationRequest != null) {
                session.removeAttribute(SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);


                LOG.debug("createAuthorizationRequest(): return saved copy.");

                return authorizationRequest;
            }
        }

        LOG.debug("createAuthorizationRequest(): create");
        return super.createAuthorizationRequest(authorizationParameters);
    }


}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomDetailsService customDetailsService;


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
      public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**");
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/fonts/**","/libs/**");
      }

      @Override
      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
          http.requestMatchers()
              .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/secure/two_factor_authentication","/exit", "/resources/**")
              .and()
              .authorizeRequests()
              .anyRequest()
              .authenticated()
              .and()
              .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
              .permitAll();
      } // @formatter:on



    @Override
    @Autowired // <-- This is crucial otherwise Spring Boot creates its own
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

//        auth//.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager)
//                .inMemoryAuthentication()
//                .withUser("demo")
//                .password("demo")
//                .roles("USER");

        auth.userDetailsService(customDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }
}
```

**TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter**

```
public class TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.class);

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    private OAuth2RequestFactory oAuth2RequestFactory;

    //These next two are added as a test to avoid the compilation errors that happened when they were not defined.
    public static final String ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED = "ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED";
    public static final String ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED = "ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED";


    @Autowired
    public void setClientDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        oAuth2RequestFactory = new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService);
    }

    private boolean twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return authorities.stream().anyMatch(
            authority -> ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED.equals(authority.getAuthority())
        );
    }



    private Map<String, String> paramsFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        for (Entry<String, String[]> entry : request.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
            params.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0]);
        }
        return params;
    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        // Check if the user hasn't done the two factor authentication.
        if (isAuthenticated() && !hasAuthority(ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED)) {
            AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = oAuth2RequestFactory.createAuthorizationRequest(paramsFromRequest(request));
            /* Check if the client's authorities (authorizationRequest.getAuthorities()) or the user's ones
               require two factor authentication. */
            if (twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(authorizationRequest.getAuthorities()) ||
                    twoFactorAuthenticationEnabled(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities())) {
                // Save the authorizationRequest in the session. This allows the CustomOAuth2RequestFactory
                // to return this saved request to the AuthenticationEndpoint after the user successfully
                // did the two factor authentication.
                request.getSession().setAttribute(CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, authorizationRequest);

                LOG.debug("doFilterInternal(): redirecting to {}", TwoFactorAuthenticationController.PATH);

                // redirect the the page where the user needs to enter the two factor authentication code
                redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response,
                        TwoFactorAuthenticationController.PATH
                           );
                return;
            } 
        }

        LOG.debug("doFilterInternal(): without redirect.");

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public boolean isAuthenticated(){
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated();
    }

    private boolean hasAuthority(String checkedAuthority){


        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(
                authority -> checkedAuthority.equals(authority.getAuthority())
                );
    }

}
```

**TwoFactorAuthenticationController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(TwoFactorAuthenticationController.PATH)

public class TwoFactorAuthenticationController {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TwoFactorAuthenticationController.class);

    public static final String PATH = "/secure/two_factor_authentication";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String auth(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        if (isAuthenticatedWithAuthority(TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED)) {
            LOG.debug("User {} already has {} authority - no need to enter code again", TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED);

            //throw ....;
        }
        else if (session.getAttribute(CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME) == null) {
            LOG.debug("Error while entering 2FA code - attribute {} not found in session.", CustomOAuth2RequestFactory.SAVED_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            //throw ....;
        }

        LOG.debug("auth() HTML.Get"); 

        return "loginSecret"; // Show the form to enter the 2FA secret
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String auth(@ModelAttribute(value="secret") String secret, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        LOG.debug("auth() HTML.Post");

        if (userEnteredCorrect2FASecret(secret)) {
            addAuthority(TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.ROLE_TWO_FACTOR_AUTHENTICATED);
            return "forward:/oauth/authorize"; // Continue with the OAuth flow
        }

        model.addAttribute("isIncorrectSecret", true);
        return "loginSecret"; // Show the form to enter the 2FA secret again
    }

    private boolean isAuthenticatedWithAuthority(String checkedAuthority){

        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(
                authority -> checkedAuthority.equals(authority.getAuthority())
                );
    }

    private boolean addAuthority(String authority){

        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> oldAuthorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
        SimpleGrantedAuthority newAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority);
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        updatedAuthorities.add(newAuthority);
        updatedAuthorities.addAll(oldAuthorities);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal(),
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials(),
                        updatedAuthorities)
        );

        return true;
    }

    private boolean userEnteredCorrect2FASecret(String secret){
        /* later on, we need to pass a temporary secret for each user and control it here */
        /* this is just a temporary way to check things are working */

        if(secret.equals("123"))
            return true;
        else;
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19261331)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I have added the key configuration files which explains the solution.