# MultiFactor autentication via spring security oauth2

Tags: angularjs, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-rest

I'm trying to implement two factor authentication via spring oauth2.

Details:

- Server side - REST
- UI - angular

Oauth2 settings:

- few in memory clients, one for ui
- "grant_type" is password
- token default (bearer)
- path to token default (/oauth/token)

How do I see it:

1) I'm getting token via user/client details with role PRE_AUTH

2) Listen success authentication and send sms to authenticated user

3) Based on token and code from sms, generate new token or enhance old with 2FA role.

---

So, I have problem with 3-rd item.
I can't get access to oauth/token with Authentication bearer...

Could I enhance token and what about refresh_token will it enhance too?

Where I should add filter for generate/enhance token?

Maybe you have other ideas how to implement it? I would be glad to hear them.

Comment: did you have any luck in implementing this?

Comment: @mayank_io This may already be answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319666/two-factor-authentication-with-spring-security-oauth2